# Удалить дубли в отсортированном массиве

Tags: java

```
public boolean noDups() {
    long value;
    for (count = 0; count < Elems - 1; count++)
        while (a[count] == a[count + 1]) {
            value = a[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < Elems; i++)
                if (Elems == i)
                    return false;
                else {
                    if (value == a[i]) {
                        for (int k = i; k < Elems - 1; k++)
                            a[k] = a[k + 1];
                        Elems--;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
  return true;
}
```

Приведенный выше метод удаляет дубли, но есть проблема. Когда количество элементов с одинаковым значением в массиве больше 3, на выходе он добавляет еще один элемент с таким же значением и дубли все равно остаются.

Пример:
long[] a = {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 11}
Результат: [2, 3, 5, 10, 11]

long[] a = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 11}
Результат: [2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 10, 11]

Comment: Если запустить второй раз то все будет нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем все так сложно?
У вас есть массив из long, на выходе такой же массив без дубликатов.
Эта задача решается в одну строчку кода, но, если вы хотите такой метод, то пожалуйста:

```
public long[] removeDuplicate(long ... sourceArray) {
    return Arrays.stream(sourceArray).distinct().toArray();
}
```